# "ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have this two methods which both of them are GET methods without parameters:

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ProductsTypes")]
    public dynamic ProductsTypes()
    {
        DbConnection.Connect();
        var result = DbConnection.GetProductsTypes();
        DbConnection.Disconnect();
        return result;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ProductsInfo")]
    public dynamic ProductsInfo()
    {
        DbConnection.Connect();
        var result = DbConnection.GetProductsInfo();
        DbConnection.Disconnect();
        return result;
    }
```

and i defined the routes to be:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action="get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

the url for each one of the methods is:

```
http://localhost:14775/api/shekem/ProductsInfo for the ProductsInfo method
http://localhost:14775/api/shekem/ProductsTypes for the ProductsTypes method
```

however, i keep getting this error:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nProductsTypes on type ShekemService.Controllers.ShekemController\r\nProductsInfo on type ShekemService.Controllers.ShekemController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

Comment: Can you try to define the ActionApi before the DefaultApi, will this work ?

Comment: It works, can u explain why?

Comment: The order is important, it will check the "to use" route in the order you provide. So both Methods have 0 Parameters, and the DefaultApi Route machtes them both...